# Proccessing Multiple cURL requests in PHP faster

Tags: php, json, http, curl, python-requests

I am trying to speed up my website by processing the cURL requests efficiently. I am running about 3 requests, two go to the same server. Here is my code:

```
$profile = curl_init();
curl_setopt($profile, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($profile, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($profile, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($profile, CURLOPT_URL,"https://owapi.net/api/v2/u/".$battletag."/stats/".$mode."?platform=".$platform);
$result = curl_exec($profile); //grab API data
curl_close($profile);
$stats = json_decode($result, true); //decode JSON data


$profile1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($profile1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($profile1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($profile1, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($profile1, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.lootbox.eu/".$platform."/us/".$battletag."/profile");
$result1 = curl_exec($profile1); //grab API data
curl_close($profile1);
$stats1 = json_decode($result1, true); 

$hero_stats = curl_init();
curl_setopt($hero_stats, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($hero_stats, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($hero_stats, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($hero_stats, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.lootbox.eu/".$platform."/us/".$battletag."/competitive-play/heroes");
$hero_play_time = curl_exec($hero_stats); //grab API data
curl_close($hero_stats);
$heroes_info = json_decode($hero_play_time, true);
```

How can I process these requests at the same time without restarting the connection? I want to speed up the load time of my site because right now, it takes a long time. Any help would be appreciated. I have heard of the curl_multi_init() method but I am not sure on how to use it properly. Any help wit that would be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not a way to make the connection faster per-se, but have you considered caching?(given that it's a viable possibility ofc). WIth that said, there's not a lot you can do about it, it mostly depends on what amount of data you're getting(as in literal amount, the less, the better) and how fast the APIs in question are.

Comment: @Andrew I have not, and that is actually a great idea. It is a possibility, I would just need to add some sort of cache update for the user to update their results.

Comment: Well there you go. I suggest [PHP Redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) (which is actually written in C, as the name does NOT imply, and is stupidly fast, unless you're running on multiple servers, then it's a bad idea). If you're running on multiple servers and need to keep the synced then I guess Memcache is a good choice as any.

Comment: Actually I take that back, PHP Redis apparently supports multiple servers. https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/master/arrays.markdown. I'm just adding this for consistency's sake, I doubt it pertains to the question on hand.

Comment: To perform parallel/concurrent calls to apis, you can do that using `curl_multi_exec`. To use it in right way check this out [Doing curl_multi_exec the right way](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/php/Download-content-with-cURL/Doing-curlmultiexec-the-right-way)

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks for all the help guys. Especially @Andrew.

I found a solution that ended up working. Posting it here for other people with a similar problem.

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($c), true);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}

$data = array(
  'https://owapi.net/api/v2/u/'.$battletag.'/stats/'.$mode.'?platform='.$platform,
  'https://api.lootbox.eu/'.$platform.'/us/'.$battletag.'/profile',
  'https://api.lootbox.eu/'.$platform.'/us/'.$battletag.'/competitive-play/heroes'
);
$r = multiRequest($data);
```

This worked, I just had to add the json_decode method over the get_contents method.

Thanks again everyone. Really appreciate the help.